# Inserting Blank Rows After a change in data in a Column

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I found this code in a previous thread. It inserts a blank row after a change in data.

Here it is:

```
sub AddBlankRows()
'
dim iRow as integer, iCol as integer
dim oRng as range

set oRng=range("a1")

irow=oRng.row
icol=oRng.column

do 
'
if cells(irow+1, iCol)<>cells(irow,iCol) then
    cells(irow+1,iCol).entirerow.insert shift:=xldown
    irow=irow+2
else
    irow=irow+1
end if
'
loop while not cells (irow,iCol).text=""
'
end sub
```

It works great, but because of this part:

```
loop while not cells (irow,iCol).text=""
```

It stops working at empty rows. I need it to ignore empty rows and only stop when there is no more data left in the range. Any ideas? I'm very new at coding!

[image: This is what my data looks like at first:]

Then, I put in the code to insert an empty row in between each change in data in the 1st column. Now, I need to run a second code that would insert an empty row in between each change in data in the 3rd Column, so it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have empty rows in your data? That is not good data design. Provide a screenshot of your data layout and explain what you would expect to happen.

Comment: Hopefully my edit made it clearer!

Comment: I've updated my answer with the Full Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a blank line counter. Then you can put in a maximum threshold.
I also added an infinite loop exit condition, just because.

This is what I have that seems to work. I Hope it Helps.

```
    Option Explicit

    Const c_intMaxBlanks As Integer = 5

    Sub AddBlankRows()

        Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
        Dim oRng As Range
        Dim intBlankCnt As Integer
        Dim intMaxBlanks As Integer
        Dim blnIsDone As Boolean
        Dim intSaveStartRow As Integer
        Dim blnStartCnt As Boolean


        blnIsDone = False

        Set oRng = Range("a1")

        iRow = oRng.Row
        iCol = oRng.Column

        blnStartCnt = False
        Do
            'Check for blank Row using length of string
            If (Len(Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol).Text)) > 0) Then
                If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
                    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

                    iRow = iRow + 2
                Else
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                End If
            Else
              iRow = iRow + 1
            End If

            'Check for blank Row using length of string
            If (Len(Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol).Text)) < 1) Then  'Check for blank Row using length of string
                If Not blnStartCnt Then
                    intSaveStartRow = iRow
                    blnStartCnt = True
                Else
                    If (intSaveStartRow + intBlankCnt) <> iRow Then
                        'restart
                        intSaveStartRow = iRow
                        intBlankCnt = 0
                    End If
                End If

                intBlankCnt = intBlankCnt + 1
            Else
                'restart
                blnStartCnt = False
                intBlankCnt = 0
            End If


            If intBlankCnt >= c_intMaxBlanks Then blnIsDone = True

            If iRow > 500 Then
                MsgBox "Stopping Loop: Maybe Infinite"
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop While (Not blnIsDone)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The last row in a column that contains data is found by the classic line:

```
Dim lastrownum as integer
lastrownum = cells(rows.count,icol).end(xlUp).Row
```

(where icol has the meaning it does in your code).  Then you can very simply "Loop While Not iRow>lastrownum" .

However, you introduce a problem with your other code, which inserts blank lines and thus moves the "last row" ever downward.  So you have to check for the last row every loop.   This is actually simpler code, just uses a few msec more time per loop.   You don't have to do anything but change the LOOP line to:

```
LOOP UNTIL irow>cells(rows.count,icol).end(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: So sorry but I am still so new at this - can you specify how I would incorporate that into the original code above?

Comment: Edited the answer to give a specific instruction.  Lucky, actually, as I forgot the code must check for the last line after every loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping me...Okay! So all I've done is replaced the "Loop While Not" line in the original code with your "Loop Until" Line. Now, I'm am receiving the "Overflow" error

Comment: Maybe it will help to add: I repeat the full code 6 times over (so that it applies to 6 different sheets of data)

Comment: Sounds like your loop is going infinite.  The other answer uses the other approach, to just add 1 to the "lastrow" number for every insert.  You could try that.  You could add in a MSGBOX("Row: " & irow)' command above the LOOP so you could watch the number go up.  It might be good to do that, learn how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

## Add Blank Rows

### Tip

The commented line `Cells(iRow + 1, cCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` adds red color into the first cell of the added row which helps a lot when trying to figure out such a code.

### Half Version

```
Sub AddBlankRows()

    Const cCol As Variant = "A"
    Const cFirstR As Long = 1

    Dim LastR As Long
    Dim iRow As Long

    LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row

    iRow = cFirstR
    Do
        If Cells(iRow, cCol) <> "" And Cells(iRow + 1, cCol) <> "" Then
            If Cells(iRow, cCol) <> Cells(iRow + 1, cCol) Then
                Cells(iRow + 1, cCol).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                'Cells(iRow + 1, cCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                LastR = LastR + 1
            End If
        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop Until iRow > LastR

End Sub
```

### Full Version

```
Sub AddBlankRows2()

    Const cCol As Variant = "A,C"
    Const cFirstR As Long = 1

    Dim vnt As Variant
    Dim LastR As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    vnt = Split(cCol, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vnt)

        LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, vnt(i)).End(xlUp).Row

        iRow = cFirstR
        Do
            If Cells(iRow, vnt(i)) <> "" And Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)) <> "" Then
                If Cells(iRow, vnt(i)) <> Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)) Then
                    Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                    'Cells(iRow + 1, vnt(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = i + 3
                    LastR = LastR + 1
                End If
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop Until iRow > LastR
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a cleaner loop... does this work...?

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("a1")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

'Need to find last row....
Dim theEND As Long
theEND = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Do While Cells(iRow, iCol).Text <> "" Or iRow <= theEND

If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is amazing!! Works great :) I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Haha, got it! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @PGCodeRider for the plug!  :)